# Populating Effectivity Satellites and handling out of order change events

Tags: data-vault

In https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/data-lt-mysteries-effectivity-satellite-driving-key-patrick-cuba/?trk=read_related_article-card_title Patrick Cuba
showed how the **insert-only** logic work when populating an effectivity satellite.

However when applying this to an event stream where we have out of order events, the ingestion and querying logic seems to explode in complexity.

## Example

Consider this series of change events depicting change in a person's employment relationship.

| person_id | employee_id | src_event_time | change_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | t1 | INSERT |
| A | X | t2 | DELETE |
| A | X | t3 | INSERT |

Consider the following scenario where the event come in the order of `t3, t1, t2` and we're
ingesting it into the effectivity link satellite table:

#### 1. Processing event t3

| person_id | employee_id | effectivity_start_date | effectivity_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | t3 | t9999 |

#### 2. Processing event t1

Here in our ingestion logic we can identify that the new event time `t1` is before the existing
event `t3`. So we set the effectivity to between `t1` and `t3`

| person_id | employee_id | effectivity_start_date | effectivity_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | t3 | t9999 |
| A | X | t1 | t3 |

#### 3. Processing event t2

This is where things get a bit weird. Our logic will have to detect that there are existing
effectivity period (from t1 to t3) and then "correct" that by adding a (t1 - t2) effectivity period.
Since our constraint is that we only ever INSERT and not update existing rows, we now have two
effectivity rows with the same start time `t1`.

| person_id | employee_id | effectivity_start_date | effectivity_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | t3 | t9999 |
| A | X | t1 | t3 |
| A | X | t1 | t2 |

## Question

Is this the correct approach? How would I go about querying the state of a relationship at a given point in time?
(For example, how would I query the relationship at `t1.5`, or `t2.5`?)

Answer (score 0):

It’s not quite correct
Data Vault Guru contains better examples, load code and query code

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Note especially that only mentionging a tool/lib, without showing how it can be used to solve the problem, is not considered an answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: Hi Patrick Cuba. I see that you have been online since I commented first time on your answer, but did not react or ask for clarification. Please [edit] your post to make more obvious how this is answering the question at the top of this page. You might want to improve your contribution by splitting it into more and smaller complete sentences.